# PHP Find Replace with characters and numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that I need to find '_frm[number]' and replace it with ''. The '_frm[number]' can be any number, so it will be dynamic.

```
    $formdata = 'category_frm1=Individual&demo_frm1=10009&value_frm1=West&solrname_frm1=dem_last_name&name=Last Name';
```

I have tried these things but am not getting what's needed returned.

```
    echo str_ireplace('_frm','',$formdata);
    echo preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $formdata );
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
    $formdata = 'category=Individual&demo=10009&value=West&solrname=dem_last_name&name=Last Name';
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/_frm\d+/i', '', $subject);
```

https://regex101.com/r/fM9vM1/1